# What is an efficient way to generate the top N pandas numeric columns with highest frequency of a particular number?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to get the top N numeric columns with the highest frequency of 1s (with the only other value being 0). I understand that the easiest way to do this would be to sum over all the numeric columns and sort them, but what is the most pythonic/efficient way to achieve this?

Sample the following dataframe:

**df**

```
Non-NumericCol1 Non-NumericCol2   Col1   Col2   Col3   ...   Coln
      ABC             PQR            1      0       1           0
      XYZ             LMN            0      0       0           1
      ABC             LMN            0      1       1           0
```

I wish to achieve, let's say, the top 3 column names.

Example: d= {'Col3': 2000, 'Col10200': 1500, 'Col4900': 1000}

I am okay with the output being in any other format (such as a pandas dataframe). There are about 10000 total columns with 6000 rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
In [113]: df
Out[113]:
  Non-NumericCol1 Non-NumericCol2  Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4  Coln
0             ABC             PQR     1     0     1     0     0
1             XYZ             LMN     0     0     0     0     1
2             ABC             LMN     0     1     1     0     0

In [114]: df.select_dtypes(['number']).sum().nlargest(3)
Out[114]:
Col3    2
Col1    1
Col2    1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: @RijulMagu, glad it helps :)

Answer (score 2):

This should give you what you're looking for. Use a list comprehension to select numeric columns, count frequency with `df.sum`, use `df.nlargest` to select the top 3 columns:

```
In [1002]: df[['Col%d' %d for d in range(1, 4)]].sum().nlargest(3)
Out[1002]: 
Col3    2
Col2    1
Col1    1
dtype: int64
```

If you want it as a dictionary, call `df.to_dict`:

```
In [1003]: _.to_dict()
Out[1003]: {'Col1': 1, 'Col2': 1, 'Col3': 2}
```